# how to enable SSL connection between F5 and Weblogic 12c?

Tags: ssl, https, weblogic, load-balancing, f5

I am trying to setup SSL connection between F5 and Weblogic. Can some one help me on how to enable SSL connection between F5 and Weblogic 12c?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you clarify what you want? Do you want ssl between client and BIG-IP, and ssl between BIG-IP and weblogic? Or do you just want ssl between client and BIG-IP and you will be offloading at BIG-IP and running in the clear between BIG-IP and weblogic?

Comment: Hi Jason,Thanks for the reply. we have ssl between client and F5. Now, we are looking for ssl between F5 and weblogic. Do we need to intsall any plugin at F5?? Also, how can we debug/verify whether the communication between F5 and weblogic  is going  using https only ??

Comment: not at all. You can re-enable ssl on the serverside by adding a serverssl profile to the virtual server. cipher options are customizable there as they are on the clientside. If you have a serverssl profile all the traffic will be encrypted between BIG-IP and the weblogic servers on that virtual server.